# rubymine で対応する括弧の行を選択中にするには

Tags: rubymine

rubymine で、カーソルがある位置に対応するブロックを選択中にするにはどうすればよいですか

たとえば、

```
def hoge
  if huga
  else
  end
end
```

とあるとき、1行目や5行目にカーソルがあれば、全部を選択していて、
2~4行目にカーソルがあれば、この範囲だけ選択するといった具合です。

Answer (score 1):

一発では出来ないようなので、

Move Caret to Code Block Start with Selection(⌥⇧⌘[) と
Extend Selection(⌥↑) / Shrink Selection(⌥↓)

を組み合わせて使うことになる(あるいはマクロ化する)と思います。